# Best way to consolidate and store user input data in each viewController

Tags: ios, swift

```
class NameViewController: UIViewController {

    var name: String?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
    }
}

class AgeViewController: UIViewController {
var age: Int?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
    }
}

class SaveViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBAction func sendData(_ sender: Any) {
        let entity = Person(name: name, age: age) // 'name'is NameViewController's name Value.
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
    }
}

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

NameViewController -> AgeViewController -> SaveViewController

I am implementing a screen with the above function as a simple example.

What's the best way to combine all the data to create an entity from the last screen?
not using Userdefaults and singleton..

Comment: best way is to store user info structure to UserDefaults. 
If it is a tabular data and multiple users to display there in table form then use core data other wise use UserDefaults to store info

Comment: If I store array data, I use UserDefaults or CoreData?
struct Person {
 let name: String
 let age: Int
 let hobbies: [Hobby]

Comment: like this
struct Person {
 let name: String
 let age: Int
 let hobbies: [Hobby]
 let freinds: [Friend]
}

Comment: if you want to store user array than core data other wise if there is only on user then use UserDefaults

Comment: Can you give me some more examples of using core data? In what situations do you mainly store in coreData?

Comment: simple and clear is if you a single user or single object to store like a User with name age hobbies address you should go with UserDefaults because its easy and less code.

Comment: if you have 3 to 1000 users the you should go for core data because its created a sqlite table in app directory and fastest way to read/write